# Will Dell Studio XPS M1640 recognize 500GB SSD?

Tags: laptop, ssd

I'd like to upgrade my laptop's 500GB to a Samsung Evo 850 500GB SSD.

I'd like to know if the SSD will be recognized by my system?

Also, will it work to have 1TB combining the SSD and my current HDD by placing my HDD in the optical drive?

Laptop: Dell Studio XPS M1640

Operating system: Ubuntu/Linux

Comment: Your question has been closed because it is asking for technical support and not a recommendation for hardware. Please see our [question quality guidelines](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/206/155) for info on how you can reword it so it can be reopened. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading the HDD to an SSD will be fine as long as the HDD is a SATA connection (which it is). You cannot place the HDD in the optical drive unless your manufacturer has a bracket for it (some of them do, most of them don't).